# Lorentz Transformation of ladder operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, lorentz-symmetry

Hello I am a beginner of QFT. I have some questions about the behavior of the momentum ladder operators under Lorentz Transformation.

For simplicity, let's consider the momentum ladder operators of a real scalar singlet $\phi$. We know that the ladder operators $a_{p}$ transform according to 
$$U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_{p}U^{-1}(\Lambda)=a^\dagger_{\Lambda p} , $$
where $U(\Lambda)$ is the unitary operator representing a given Lorentz Transformation $\Lambda$ (e.g *Peskin p.59*).

I tried to derive this identity in the following manner. Let's consider a typical situation in special relativity. Alice has a set of inertia coordinate $x$, Bob has another set of inertia coordinate $x^\prime = \Lambda x$. If a classical particle is observed to have momentum $p$ in the frame of Alice, it will be observed to have momentum $\Lambda p$ by Bob. In quantum mechanics, Alice observes the particle to be in a state $|p\rangle$ while Bob observes the particle to be in a state $|\Lambda p\rangle$, and the two single particle states are related by a unitary operator $U(\Lambda)$ representing a given Lorentz Transformation $\Lambda$. In summary, 
$$|\Lambda p\rangle=U(\Lambda)|p\rangle . $$
This then implies 
$$ a^\dagger_{\Lambda p}|0\rangle=U(\Lambda)a^\dagger _{p}|0\rangle , $$ 
where $|0\rangle$ on both sides is the ground state of the free field theory. We are then led to the conclusion that 
$$ a^\dagger_{\Lambda p}=U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_{p} , $$ 
in contrast to the standard result. Is there something wrong in my reasoning?

I observe that if we assume the vacuum ket $|0\rangle$ to be Lorentz invariant, i.e 
$$ U(\Lambda)|0\rangle=|0\rangle , $$
then we may write
$$ a^\dagger_{\Lambda p}|0\rangle =
  U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_{p}|0\rangle =
  U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_{p}U^{-1}(\Lambda) U(\Lambda)|0\rangle =
  U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_{p}U^{-1}(\Lambda)|0\rangle . $$
Then the standard result 
$$ a^\dagger_{\Lambda p} = U(\Lambda)a_{p}U^{-1}(\Lambda) $$ 
is recovered. Is the assumption of the Lorentz invariance of the vacuum state of free field theory correct?

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I believe the answer is that your reasoning only proves that $a_{\Lambda p}^\dagger=U(\Lambda)a_p^\dagger$ *when acting on the vacuum* $\lvert0\rangle$. Generally speaking, $A\lvert0\rangle=B\lvert0\rangle$ does not imply $A=B$ (which is obvious if you think about it in terms of regular vectors). The reason the operators are equal when acting on the vacuum is precisely what you note: that the vacuum is Lorentz invariant.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're trying to prove the transformation properties of these operators by acting on the vacuum, I believe there is a way to reach the conclusion of both the invariance of the vacuum and the relation
$$a^\dagger_{\Lambda p}=U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_pU^{-1}(\Lambda) ,$$
without assuming a priori that either of them holds. You can do this as following.
Consider a 2-particle state $|\vec{p}, \vec{q}\rangle$. Then, using the fact that
$$|\Lambda p\rangle=U(\Lambda)|p\rangle , $$
we get (by the same reasoning explained in the question)
$$U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_\vec{p}a^\dagger_{\vec{q}}|0\rangle=a^\dagger_{\Lambda\vec{p}}a^\dagger_{\Lambda\vec{q}}|0\rangle.$$
Introducing $U^{-1}(\Lambda)U(\Lambda)$ between the two operators on the left-hand side, we get
$$[U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_\vec{p}U^{-1}(\Lambda)]U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_{\vec{q}}|0\rangle=a^\dagger_{\Lambda\vec{p}}a^\dagger_{\Lambda\vec{q}}|0\rangle.$$
Now, for all the creation operators to transform in a similar way, we need to introduce $U^{-1}(\Lambda)U(\Lambda)$ again as follows
$$[U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_\vec{p}U^{-1}(\Lambda)][U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_{\vec{q}}U^{-1}(\Lambda)]U(\Lambda)|0\rangle=a^\dagger_{\Lambda\vec{p}}a^\dagger_{\Lambda\vec{q}}|0\rangle.$$
Thus, the only way to get a consistent result (one that applies the same for eevry creation operator), we need
$$U(\Lambda)|0\rangle=|0\rangle,$$
i.e. the vacuum is Lorentz invariant. The transformation of the operators -modulo multipliers that come from a Lorentz covariant normalization choice for 1-particle states- follows immediately as
$$U(\Lambda)a^\dagger_\vec{p}U^{-1}(\Lambda)=a^\dagger_{\Lambda\vec{p}}$$
To get the correct factor of $\sqrt{\dfrac{E_{\Lambda\vec{p}}}{E_{\vec{p}}}}$ that Peskin puts in front of $a^\dagger_{\Lambda\vec{p}}$, you can either follow a similar process as above or just assume that the vacuum is Lorentz invariant (which makes intuitive sense) and proceed with your proof, but now use a Lorentz-covariant normalization
$$|\vec{p}\rangle=\sqrt{2E_\vec{p}}a^\dagger_\vec{p}|0\rangle$$

Comment: It is the last part of your answer where I get stuck i.e., where the |p> states are normalized as per the last equation. I don't understand how to get the Eq. 2.38 of Peskin's book. It's the factors of energy that bother me. I am afraid we cannot simply pass the unitary operators through the energies, right? The energy is not a scalar under Lorentz transformation, although p^2 is. What is the resolution of this? 

I don't know if I should add a separate question, but this seems like a good place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You have more or less answered your own question. Yes indeed, the vacuum must be Lorentz invariant, otherwise the Lorentz invariance would be spontaneously broken.

Comment: But it seems like the inverse of Lorentz operator can be dropped anyway (because it acts on a vacuum state and makes no difference), why does the standard results bother keeping it?